# Using latest version of Optidef on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, optidef

I am using optidef package for writing optimization problem in latex. I am trying to use \breakObjective command but Overleaf gives me error. This happens because this command is defined for optidef version of 2.5 and newer. However, Overleaf does not support 2017 version of package as when I check the log file it shows:

```
 Package: optidef 2016/08/07 - version=2.0
```

Now I wonder if there is anyway to directly add the latest version of the optidef to Overleaf.

Thanks

Comment: You can download the .sty from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/optidef?lang=en) and upload to your project folder on Overleaf. The version in your folder should be used instead of Overleaf's.

Comment: Or use Overleaf v2 https://www.overleaf.com/blog/641-try-out-overleaf-v2, which is on TL2017 and has `optidef 2017/06/21
− version=2.5`